Error in f1(x) : argument "y" is missing, with no default
f <- function(x,y){2x^2(y-2)^2+6xy}
integrate(f, -2, 4)
#Error in f1(x) : argument "y" is missing, with no default

f <- function(x, y) { 2*x^2*(y-2)^2 + 6*x*y}
integrate(f, -2, 4)

You will want to carefully read the
documentation.
It explains that the library function you're calling supports

Adaptive quadrature of functions of one variable over a finite or infinite interval.

You may want to define y as a constant,
so f is a function of just one variable.
